# Jackson upgrade causing deserialization error with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Upgraded to jackson 2.12.x and it's been failing my builds in Kotlin 1.3.x which seemingly for a method not being available. I'm unable to figure out if this is breaking change coming from Jackson.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.reflect.KClass.getSealedSubclasses()Ljava/util/List; 
|   at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.findSubtypes(KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.kt:72) 
|   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findSubtypes(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:263) 
|   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findSubtypes(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:263) 
|   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.StdSubtypeResolver._collectAndResolveByTypeId(StdSubtypeResolver.java:288) 
... jackson internals omitted ...
|   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3601) 
|   at com.xxxxxxx.util.JacksonSerializationHelper.deserialize(JacksonSerializationHelper.kt:94)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some things have been depreciated in the upgrade.

You need to look at the upgrade notes, because this method doesn't exist anymore `getSealedSubclasses()`

You might find the answer here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Releases

If you cant find it here, you will need to create a bug report

Comment: `getSealedSubclasses()` is a kotlin API. This is a jackson upgrade. Or do you mean a jackson function is now usinng something else that isn't in Kotlin 1.3?

Comment: Yes i think upgrade both